# use drop down menu to query mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Beginner here; I have searched many examples, still need some help.
I would like for the user to select an option from a dropdown box, and that option will query a table in mysql.  I don't understand how to (in my html file) show the select statment in getprojectstatus.php.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Status Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body style="background:#19245e url('images/fade.png')repeat-x;font-size:12px;font-family: Arial;line-height:18px;color:#FFFFFF;">
    <script>
        function displayProject(option)
            {
            var x;
            if (option=='sciplay')
            {                        
             x="show Sciplay selected, show notes, status, etc..."
            }

            else if (option=='oklahoma')
            {
             x="show OK selected, show..."
            }

            else if (option=='northdakota')
            {
             x="show North Dakota selected, show..."
            }

            else if (option=='audit')
            {
             x="show Audit selected, show..."
            }

            else if (option=='sggaming')
            {                           
             x="show SG Gaming selected, show..."
            }

            else if (option=='all')
            {
             x="..."//(option=(1+2+3+4+5))
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
            }

    </script>

    <div align="center">
        <TABLE BORDER="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><img src='images/header.png'/>
            </TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD>
                <TABLE BORDER="0" bgcolor="C0C0C0" align="left">
                    <TH>Projects
                    </TH>
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                            <FORM action="getprojectstatus.php" method="post">
                                <SELECT onload="displayProject(this.value);" onchange="displayProject(this.value);">
                                    <OPTION VALUE='all'>ALL</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='sciplay'>Sciplay</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='oklahoma'>Oklahoma</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='northdakota'>North Dakota</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='audit'>Audit SSAE16</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='sggaming'>SG Gaming</OPTION>
                                </SELECT>
                            </FORM>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>

                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD>
                <p id="demo">
                </p>
            </TD>
        </TR>

        </TABLE>

    </div>
</body>
```

and my getprojectstatus.php file:

```
<?php
//create connection variables
$host=`localhost`;
$user=`dashboard`;
$pw=`password`;
$db=`status`;
//create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pw", "$db");
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//take input from form and store as var queries
$option= $_POST['option'];

if ($option == 'sciplay')
{
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=1"
}

else if ($option == 'oklahoma')
{
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=2"
}

else if ($option == 'northdakota')
{
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=3"
}

else if ($option == 'audit')
{
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=4"
}

else if ($option == 'sggaming')
{
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=5"
}

else ($option == 'all')
{
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM status"
}

//store query as var result
$queries=$query;
$result=@mysqli_query($con,"$query");
//echo var result in table format
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['project'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['entry'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
//close mysql connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you explain where you're stuck?  What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: When i select an option from the drop down, the select statement in the php is not shown.

Comment: What's the name of your html file?  Have you shown the whole file here, or is there other PHP going on in there?  I ask to help give me context of *your* understanding of how your page works.  You've made a simple (and common, at the beginning) miscalculation in how data is passed around.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it looks like you haven't fully grasped the client/server model employed in web based systems (we were all there at the beginning).

Here's a quick rundown, and then we'll talk about where you're issue lies.

1. You open a browser and type in a URL, hit enter
2. Your browser sends a request to the server that hosts the URL you entered
3. The server parses the request and loads up the specific file that was requested.  For our purposes, that means running the PHP file to ultimately generate an HTML and javascript output
4. It sends this HTML (and javascript) to the browser.  No executable PHP is ever sent to the browser, it all stays on the server.
5. Your browser receives this HTML (and javascript) and displays it.
6. Your browser can execute any javascript on the page, but if it needs information that is not already in your page source, *it has to request it from the server*.  It can do this one of two ways: a) you can send a whole new request to the server, with the correct parameters such that the information you want is included up front or b) you can run an ajax request to pull the information you need, and then insert it into your page

So, at first glance it looks like the breakdown is occurring between step 5 and 6, you've loaded up a whole page in the browser, and it needs more information **from the server** but you're never actually sending that request to the server.  If you *were* to send that request to the server (by either adding a submit button to your form, or adding a form submit request to your `displayProject()` function), then you've got no way (currently) to insert that new information into your existing page.

So, there's two potential answers to your problem:

***If you want to understand better how to write a PHP application because you intend to do more of this in the future:***

... then you should rewrite these two separate files as one single file. (I've dropped your code in pretty much as-is, I haven't done *any* checking for errors)

```
<?php
//create connection variables
$host=`localhost`;
$user=`dashboard`;
$pw=`password`;
$db=`status`;
//create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pw", "$db");
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//take input from form and store as var queries
$option= $_POST['option'];

if ($option == 'sciplay')
{
    $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=1"
}

else if ($option == 'oklahoma')
{
    $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=2"
}

else if ($option == 'northdakota')
{
    $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=3"
}

else if ($option == 'audit')
{
    $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=4"
}

else if ($option == 'sggaming')
{
    $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=5"
}

else ($option == 'all')
{
    $queries = "SELECT * FROM status"
}

//store query as var result
$queries=$query;
$result=@mysqli_query($con,"$query");

//The actual echo of the table display was moved to the area of the page it actually needs to go

//close mysql connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Status Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body style="background:#19245e url('images/fade.png')repeat-x;font-size:12px;font-family: Arial;line-height:18px;color:#FFFFFF;">
    <script>
    function displayProject(option)
        {
        var x;
        if (option=='sciplay')
        {                        
         x="show Sciplay selected, show notes, status, etc..."
        }

        else if (option=='oklahoma')
        {
         x="show OK selected, show..."
        }

        else if (option=='northdakota')
        {
         x="show North Dakota selected, show..."
        }

        else if (option=='audit')
        {
         x="show Audit selected, show..."
        }

        else if (option=='sggaming')
        {                           
         x="show SG Gaming selected, show..."
        }

        else if (option=='all')
        {
         x="..."//(option=(1+2+3+4+5))
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
        }

    </script>

    <div align="center">
        <TABLE BORDER="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><img src='images/header.png'/>
            </TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD>
                <TABLE BORDER="0" bgcolor="C0C0C0" align="left">
                    <TH>Projects
                    </TH>
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                            <!--
                            SOME CHANGES HERE: The form action is now pointing
                            to this same file, so that when you submit your form,
                            it goes back to this same file.
                            Also, I gave your select tag a "name" attribute so
                            that when you submit it, it'll actually be accessible
                            in the $_POST['option'] variable 
                            -->
                            <FORM action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                                <SELECT name="option" onload="displayProject(this.value);" onchange="displayProject(this.value);">
                                    <OPTION VALUE='all'>ALL</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='sciplay'>Sciplay</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='oklahoma'>Oklahoma</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='northdakota'>North Dakota</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='audit'>Audit SSAE16</OPTION>
                                    <OPTION VALUE='sggaming'>SG Gaming</OPTION>
                                </SELECT>
                                <input type="submit" value="Reload Form">
                            </FORM>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>

                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD>
                <!-- a <p> tag can't technically hold a <table> tag, but one thing at a time here -->
                <p id="demo">
                    <?php
                    // I'm just lifting your structure out and placing it here for clarity purposes.
                    // really, you can just write these tags out in HTML directly,
                    // not go into PHP and echo them
                    echo "<table border='1'>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Project</th>
                            <th>Subject</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>";

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['project'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['entry'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    ?>
                </p>
            </TD>
        </TR>

        </TABLE>

    </div>
</body>
```

... so, what's going on here is that I've changed it up so that the data is being built *and* used, all in the same file.  Your page now doesn't *need* to request new information, it's all right there, and if you want to change the form, then you submit and it requests the whole page again, now with the new information.

That's all well and good, but may not be exactly how you want your page to work.  That said, you should understand how that process functions because any PHP application of even basic complexity will need to work in that way at least in part.

Now...
***If you just want this page to function the way it appears you -want- it to function, i.e. you build your page, then request new information to update your page on form request:***

... then we can get that done.  Again, I haven't done any checking for errors.  First things first, though, put this in your `<head>` tags:

```
<head>
    <title>Status Dashboard</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

... we're going to be using jquery, just because in our case here, it let's us just worry about running the ajax request rather than bother setting up all of the necessary ins and outs.  Then you want to add this to your `displayProject` function (just before the closing } ):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getprojectstatus.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'option='+option,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#demo').html(data);
    }
});
```

... all that's going on there is that you're sending your "option" selection to getprojectstatus.php, that file is generating your HTML output for your table, and then once it's received, it runs "success", which just inserts the data directly into the element with the "demo" id attribute.  You should consider changing that to a `<div>`, at minimum, as the `<p>` might cause headaches.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. If StackOverflow would let me upvote twice I would.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but this might work for you:

```
<FORM action="getprojectstatus.php" method="post">
 <SELECT onload="displayProject(this.value);" onchange="displayProject(this.value);">
  <OPTION VALUE='none'>ALL</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE='1'>Sciplay</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE='2'>Oklahoma</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE='3'>North Dakota</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE='4'>Audit SSAE16</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE='5'>SG Gaming</OPTION>
 </SELECT>
</FORM>
```

And then in your PHP file:

```
$option= $_POST['option'];

$queries = "SELECT * FROM status"
if ($option != 'none'){
 $queries = "SELECT * FROM status where project=".$option
}
```

I would also recommend researching some PHP Frameworks, maybe [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and learning MVC patterns.

Comment: Thanks Teodor, that is more elegant PHP code.  I don't think that I asked my question clearly.  When the user clicks on an option from the drop down menu, I want the results from the mysql table to be shown to the user in the HTML page.

I would want the var x in the html to echo the select statement from the php query

Comment: What is the exact problem with your code. Any errors or not doing what you want. Please help me understand.

Comment: My code is not doing what I want it to do.
How do I set the var x in my function displayProject to show the query that is run in the php?